# User has no rights when he is in a group with rights

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have a group with contribute permissions to a List:
[image]

Inside that group there is a user
[image]

When I check permissions for that user on the List he has no access
[image]

Why doesn't he have contribute rights?

Comment: I've made a new discovery: The problem is only with one user.  Every other user seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does the group have permissions to the list?  I can't tell but the contribute permissions for the group look like they are at the site level.

Go to the list and then to go List Tools Ribbon -> List -> List Permissions

Look to see that it says:
"This list inherits permissions from its parent"

If that is NOT there then the list has unique permissions and you have two options:

1. Re-Inherit permissions to the parent site
2. Add the Quality Contributors group to have permissions on the list.

Comment: This list does inherit permission from its parent.

I've made a new discovery: The problem is only with one user.  Every other user seems to work fine.